# How to construct C++ macro that uses 'this' keyword for use in non-statics AND statics?

Tags: c++, static, macros

I have a logging macro that I'd like to expand to include the name of the instance of the object from which it is called.

I've introduced a base class for all objects to inherit off, for example:

```
class ObjectInstance
{
public:
  ObjectInstance( string name );
  virtual string GetName() const = 0;
}
```

And the macro looks something like this:

```
#define LOG( type, msg ) LogHandler( type, msg, dynamic_cast<ObjectInstance*>( this ) )
```

With *LogHandler* function like:

```
void LogHandler( string type,
                 string msg,
                 ObjectInstance* instance )
{
  string instanceName = "Unknown";

  if( instance != NULL )
  {
    instanceName = instance->GetName();
  }

  const string output = type + " | " + msg + " | " + instanceName;

  // Do logging stuff...
}
```

This seems to be panning out, but I quickly realised it won't compile when the macro is called from a static context... I'm drawing a blank on how to proceed and haven't turned up much online so far.

**Non-static context example:**

```
class SomeObject : public ObjectInstance
{
  SomeObject( const string& name )
  :
    m_name( name )
  {
    LOG( Info, "Created SomeObject" )
  }

  virtual string GetName() const { return m_name; }
}

SomeObject* ob = new SomeObject( "SomeObject123" );
```

Expected output: *Info | Created SomeObject | SomeObject123*

**Static context example - this doesn't compile, of course:**

```
class SomeStaticObject
{
  static void DoSomething()
  {
    LOG( Info, "Doing something..." )
  }
}

SomeStaticObject::DoSomething();
```

Expected output: *Info | Doing something... |*

I'd really like to stick with just the one macro for both static and non-static contexts as it's already widely used throughout a large codebase.

Comment: why dont you make `getname` static and pass the class type to the loghandler instead of an instance?

Comment: So what do you want "getname" to do then? Why is it nonstatic?

Comment: ah wait... I though the name is for the class not the instances. In that case, yes, what should the loghandler do if there is no instance whose name it should log? Maybe just make the parameter optional

Comment: Heh sorry, clearly I wasn't thinking properly when I typed that out... I'll fix it now.

Comment: I see no way to use a single macro. Static methods have no `this`. You can have both macros invoke the same log handler function, with the static version passing a `nullptr`, for the object pointer.

Comment: Yep, I'm really hoping to avoid that, though.

Comment: Well, sometimes one's hopes have to be dashed... You could use one macro, but only if every method explicitly declares something like `ObjectInstance * const logging_object=this;` or `ObjectInstance * const logging_object=nullptr;`, and the macro references `logging_object`.

Comment: I dont know of a way to detect whether the surrounding function is static or not.

Comment: With "static if", perhaps you can evaluate "__PRETTY_FUNCTION__" (nonstandard) and inspect whether or not it is static at compile time and then use or not use "this"?

Comment: Are you referring to static_if as a language feature (if it's in yet - we're running VS2015 and the compiler doesn't seem to support it) or the library?

Comment: I think there is a way to distinguish const nonstatic members from nonconst/static members though, by using `decltype` on a nonstatic member, but this is only half the solution.

Comment: If you requirethe logging code to type the name of the surrounding function, then together with the class name you can inspect the functions adress type to decide whether or not it is a static function.

Comment: That sounds promising, I'm not at my machine right now but will explore it.

Answer (score 2):

> I've introduced a base class for all objects to inherit off

Woah! stop right there. This is c++, not a scripting language.

Adding a common base class to every class in your project limits flexibility, tightly couples everything with your logger and nudges you down the slippery slope to collections of `ObjectInstance`, which destroys all type safety.

There is a better way:

First, define a tag class:

```
template<class T>
struct name_tag
{};
```

Then make LogHandler a template function:

```
template<class T>
void LogHandler( string type,
                 string msg,
                 T* instance )
{
    // get the name by deferring to instance_name(name_tag<>);
    .... << instance_name(name_tag<std::decay_t<T>>()) << ...
}
```

Now we just have to write an instance_name for any type passed into LogHandler.

```
// this is your object
struct MyThing {};

// this is its name_generator.
const char* instance_name(name_tag<MyThing>)
{
  return "MyThing";
}
```

Note that the return type for each name generator can be anything you want, provided it's streamable.

Full example, including optional contents-printer:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

#define LOG(type, msg, obj) LogHandler(type, msg, std::addressof(obj))

template<class T>
struct name_tag
{};

template<class T> const char* instance_name(name_tag<T>) { return typeid(T).name(); }
template<class T> const char* object_contents(const T*) { return "{}"; }

template<class T>
void LogHandler( std::string type,
                std::string msg,
                T* instance )
{
    std::clog << "type: " << type
    << ", message: " << std::quoted(msg)
    << " : object type: " << instance_name(name_tag<std::decay_t<T>>())
    << " " << object_contents(instance)
    << std::endl;
}

// this is your object
struct MyThing {
    int a = 4;
    double b = 6.6;
};

// this is its name_generator.
const char* instance_name(name_tag<MyThing>)
{
    return "MyThing";
}

// this is a contents printer.
std::string object_contents(const MyThing* p)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "{ a: " << p->a
    << ", b: " << p->b
    << " }";
    return ss.str();
}


int main()
{
    MyThing t;

    LOG("whatever goes here", "hello", t);

}
```

expected output:

```
type: whatever goes here, message: "hello" : object type: MyThing { a: 4, b: 6.6 }
```

Comment: I think I've just about wrapped my head around this and it looks cool, but I'm not sure it'll integrate with the macro - that is to say, i won't be able to adapt the existing macro to use it?

Comment: @grae22 why not? Doesn't the existing macro just call a function?

Comment: It does, but I don't quite understand how to construct the macro to call the LogHandler method when it is called from a static context - in particular, what do I specify for the 3rd param "T* instance"?

Comment: @grae22 just pass it straight to the function. T will be deduced and the correct function will be invoked.

Comment: Thanks, I'm nursing some flu and I'm probably just being quite slow :)

Comment: @grae22 full example. note that I provide default implementations of instance_name and object_contents so you don't have to write them for every class. But if you want them, you just provide them near the class definition itself (not as part of it). Now logging is distinct from object behaviour so they're not coupled.

Comment: @RichardHodges: "*This is c++, not a scripting language.*" I take issue with your characterization of scripting languages doing this stuff. This anti-pattern is the stuff of C#/Java; most scripting languages use duck typing, where you *don't care* if they "inherit" from a common "base class". As long as they provide the functions you use, it's fine.

Comment: @NicolBolas :) I'm a victim of my prejudices here. I regard c# and java as glorified scripting languages because of this "everything is derived from object" idiocy. I am of course, being unkind to scripting languages.

Comment: Just updated my question to clarify what I'm after. I'm looking into your answer here to see if I can adapt it to my needs - I'd prefer to avoid having to explicitly pass in the object when calling LOG. In fact, if I'm explicitly passing in the object I think I could handle the problem of static contexts by simply passing in some token (NULL, perhaps).

Comment: @grae22 or pass in a token like this: `struct static_context {};` and specialise for that.